# Can't render page(express-handlebars) using post of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, post, express-handlebars

In html when I click button I catch events with function

```
function ButtonClickGoToNewsPage(){
    $.post('/gotonewspage')
}
```

I using nodejs and handlebars

```
ShowTrangQuanLi(req, res) {
    res.render('NewsPage', {
        layout: 'LMain'
    })
}
```

But it does not render NewsPage.

I can use

```
<form action="gotonewspage" method="post">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

it will work but I want to use jquery post because I need to perform some function.How I can solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: By using `$.post` you are sending an [XML HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). You will need to handle the response and do something with the returned HTML. See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/